# Ionic 1 Angular translate static files loader not working in Android

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-translate

My app is using Angular Translate. It works very fine on the web using `ionic serve`. But when I build it to Android, I use chrome inspector to check the network requests, the json file isn’t loaded and no error is shown. 
I have checked an earlier question, my prefix doesn’t have `/` at the beginning.
I put a breakpoint in the `angular-translate-loader-static-files.js` and it doesn't stop there in runtime in Android.

```
$translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
    prefix: 'js/locales/',
    suffix: '.json'
})
//locales is a string type variable e.g "fi","en"
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage(locale).fallbackLanguage('en').useSanitizeValueStrategy('escapeParameters');
```

My directory structure

```
—-www
------js
---------locales
-----------en.json
-----------fi.json
```

Comment: did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @raghav710 please see my answer below for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I manage a workaround by adding locales json strings to the app module using constants:

```
angular.module("app").constant("en",{ 
  "YOUR_ID":"Your translation",
  "YOUR_ID_2":"Your translation"
})
```

Then load the constants in when you config angular translate:

```
angular.module("app").
config(function($translateProvider,en){//inject your locale constants here
  //...your own configuration
  $trans‌​lateProvider.transla‌​tions("en",en)

})
```

By doing this we still have separate locale files so we can pass them to translators or whoever...